# Rails - Importing a CSV file of emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

anyone know of a GEM for importing a CSV full of emails?

The challenge is that given a list of emails like:

```
"fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>, "fname lname" <yada@yada.com>
```

I want to extract both the name and the email, not just the email.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby has [built-in CSV support](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) and there are good gems for managing CSV files, such as [FasterCSV](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/). That being said, it doesn't look like you have a "proper" CSV (which stores tabular data), but rather just a list of data separated by commas. You could use a regular expression like [this one](http://rubular.com/r/PrYZgH4xlb) to get the date you want:

```
data = '"Some Guy" <some@guy.com>, "Another Person" <another@person.com>, "One More" <one@more.com>'
regex = /("([^"]*)" <([^>]*)>)/

data.scan(regex) do |match|
  puts "Name: #{match[1]}, Email: #{match[2]}"
end

# Output:

Name: Some Guy, Email: some@guy.com
Name: Another Person, Email: another@person.com
Name: One More, Email: one@more.com
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon but that doesn't seem to be working. I submit a post which shows in the logs as: Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XsU9VCt35gFB/ZQKDibUnXvX5d1LxytwenE+1OiT74Y=", "utf8"=>"✓", "group_id"=>"58", "emails"=>"bob@aol.com, dkkjdkjdkdkj@gmail.com, dsjakkjdskjdasjk1123@aol.com, Brad Smith <bbbb@intuit.com>, jkdkjdkj@aol.com, re joyce <adsdddd@yahoo-inc.com>"}

Comment: But then when I do the follow, there are 0 matches.     @emails_submitted = params[:emails]
    email_csv_regex = /("([^"]*)" <([^>]*)>)/
    @emails_submitted.scan(email_csv_regex) do |match|
      Rails.logger.info 'Hello'
      Rails.logger.info "Name: #{match[1]}, Email: #{match[2]}"
      Rails.logger.info 'Good bye'
    end

Comment: Also does this REGEX allow for emails that aren't in the FNAME LNAME <asddsa@asdsd.net> format but rather are in the xx@xxxx.com format only?

Comment: The regex I used was an example based on the *exact format* you showed in your question, namely, (1) open double quote, (2) name, (3) close double quote, (4) space, (5) open angle bracket, (6) email address, (7) close angle bracket. If your file isn't just like that you'll have to tweak the regular expression. Rubular is a great tool for this.

Comment: Another option would be to call [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001165) on the data (e.g. `data.split(", ")` or similar), and then parse each element individually.